# Can I make Chrome's background transparent?

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to make my Chrome (El Capitan) transparent and see any apps beneath it.

Is it possible to make the background transparent in Chrome?

Comment: No it is not possible, according to [Is it possible to make the HTML  transparent in Google Chrome?](//stackoverflow.com/q/18653630)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the answer over SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653630/is-it-possible-to-make-the-html-body-transparent-in-google-chrome), which was pointed out by @DavidPostill at the comment, there is no way to make it transparent as of October 2017.

Answer (score 0):

How do you explain this? I am not sure how this happened. [transparent chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL8gV.jpg)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.